# c++ static interface: when the object has pointer

Tags: c++

This may be a naive question :)

I have an interface

```
void ImportantFunc(const vector<People>& people_list) { ... }
```

My understanding is within the function, people_list is not going to be modified, similar for each of the element in the people_list. But if the people class holds a pointer to another object:

```
class People {
    private: 
      Bank* bank_account;
}
```

Could I modify the bank information inside 'ImportantFunc'?

Comment: The vector and its contents is constant. That means you can't modify the vector itself, nor the `People` objects in the vector. ***But*** the `bank_account` pointer is pointing to a totally separate object, one that is *not* constant. That of course assumes that you're able to access the `Bank` object that the `bank_account` variable is pointing to.

Comment: No that's a function not an interface (an pure abstract basesclass is an interface). Also I would model a BankAccount as a seperate class that models the relation between a bank and a Person (class). You would still be a Person without a BankAccount. So you have a `std::vector<Person> People;` not a People class. Also `raw pointers` should be avoided in C++ model ownership with `std::unique_ptr` if needed. (or maybe std::shared_ptr if a person and a bank share an account)

Comment: WhatABeautifulWorld Since this question is still open I wonder if you need some clarification. Please ask under the answers if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. You won't be able to modify the actual pointer, but what it points at.

A fully valid demo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Bank {
    int money = 0;
};

class People {
public:
    People(Bank& b) : bank_account(&b) {}

    void add_money(int x) const { // can be const qualified
        bank_account->money += x;
    }
    int get_saldo() const {
        return bank_account->money;
    }
private:
    Bank* bank_account;
};

void ImportantFunc(const std::vector<People>& people_list) {
    for(auto& p : people_list) {
        p.add_money(123);
    }
}

void PrintSaldo(const std::vector<People>& people_list) {
    for(auto& p : people_list) {
        std::cout << p.get_saldo() << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    Bank b;
    std::vector<People> vec{b};
    
    PrintSaldo(vec);
    ImportantFunc(vec);
    PrintSaldo(vec);
}
```

Output:

```
0
123
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, no, you can't modify any `Bank` object in a function outside `People`, because nothing exposes it to the outside world.

It's normal to design a class such that you  only expose a `const` view of pointed-to objects from `const` member functions.